# Large folder of XML files needs to become large folder of Excel workbooks

Tags: python, xml, excel

I use SAS to generate dozens of reports in XML format which I then have to save as Excel workbooks.  Unfortunately I don't see a way to programmatically do that in SAS.  Ideally I would like a script that can just eat up all the .XML files and spit out .XLS.  I've parsed out the XML using:

```
import os, sys
import openpyxl
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

path = 'C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\xml'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if not filename.endswith('.xml'): continue
    fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
    tree = ET.parse(fullname)
```

And am trying to use openpyxl to save as .XLS in the same path while keeping the .XML files.

Is this possible?

Comment: What about using Excel's native XML reader and then just save as .xls? Try doing one manually and use Macro Recorder to view what commands it involves. Then just scale it so it handles a whole folder or however you have your XMLs stored.

Comment: [How do I export from SAS to Excel files: Let me count the ways](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2012/02/11/export-excel-methods/)

Comment: We use the excel xp tagset in SAS so it comes out as a formatted XML file.

Comment: Why not use ODS EXCEL instead of ODS TAGSETS EXCELXP?

Comment: @nbayly that's brilliant, I didn't even think of an excel macro.  Thanks.

Comment: @momo Glad I could help. Send my best to Appa :p